# Session blocked

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

I'm having trouble with using the PHP session.

I use AJAX to send a request to an action in an app, that is used just to trigger the starting of a process. The progress of this is stored in a session variable.
The problem is that I can't access this variable from another action until the first one is finished.
Something like this:

```
public function startWorkingAction() {  
$namespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('progressOfWork');  
$namespace->totalItems = 0;   
$namespace->processedItems = 0;  
//... processing items  
$namespace->totalItems = $itemCount;   
foreach($items as $item) {  
//process a single item  
$namespace->processedItems++;  
}  
}
```

And I have another action to check the progress so far:

```
public function checkProgressAction() {  
$namespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('progressOfWork');  
echo json_encode(array(  
'total' => $namespace->totalItems,  
'processed' => $namespace->processedItems  
));  
}
```

Both actions are triggered with AJAX requests. The problem is that I can't access the session namespace until the first action is done working.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: AJAX works in a synchronous manner and not async. If both ajax requests are made from the same page then second one will wait for the first to finish. Maybe wrong but this is what i usually observe. Unless you specifically set them to be async

Comment: I cancel the first request forcefully (I need it just to start the process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that I can't access the session namespace until the first action is done working.  Where am I going wrong?

You aren't.  This is the intended behavior of PHP sessions that use the default "files" [handler](http://php.net/session.customhandler).

Upon `session_start`, PHP will obtain an [exclusive file lock](http://php.net/flock) on the session file stored on disk.  The lock will be released only when the session data has been written to disk and the file closed.  There is no way to disable this behavior short of writing your own custom session handler.

Comment: Thanks for the custom session handlers link.

Comment: You might want to make sure that Zend Framework doesn't already have one written for you.  I vaguely recall that one existed, but Google's only pulling up blog posts, so maybe I'm misremembering.  Also note that a lack of locking can result in some *weird* "data loss" behavior if you change session data frequently.  It's all about the race conditions...

Comment: Zend does provide locking and unlocking, but I can't get it to work at the moment.